# Cannot express tuple conversion with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I try to set the theme (include the background and a picture) for my app. I try this code:

```
import UIKit

enum AppTheme {
    case dayMode
    case nightMode

    func setBackground() -> (UIImage, UIImage) {
        switch self {

        case .dayMode():
            let backgroundImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DayMode")
            let sunControllerImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sun")
            return (backgroundImage, sunControllerImage)

        case .nightMode():
            let backgroundImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NightMode")
            let sunControllerImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "moon")
            return (backgroundImage, sunControllerImage)

        }
    }
}
```

then in `viewDidLoad`, I try:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        (backgroundImg.image, sunControllerImg.image) = AppTheme.nightMode.setBackground()

    }
```

However, there is an error:

> Cannot express tuple conversion `(UIImage, UIImage)` to `(UIImage?, UIImage?)` (aka `(Optional<UIImage>, Optional<UIImage>)`).

Is there anyway to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
enum AppTheme {
    case dayMode
    case nightMode

    func setBackground() -> (UIImage?, UIImage?) {
        switch self {

        case .dayMode():
            let backgroundImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DayMode")
            let sunControllerImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sun")
            return (backgroundImage, sunControllerImage)

        case .nightMode():
            let backgroundImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NightMode")
            let sunControllerImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "moon")
            return (backgroundImage, sunControllerImage)

        }
    }
}
```

cause UIImage is  Optional .

Swift have  a  concept of failable initializers and UIImage is have  of them. The initializer returns an Optional so if the image cannot be created it will return nil.

Comment: I have tried the second way but it seems that I cannot unwrap the UIImage type. The first way works well, thanks

Comment: It seems I still cannot load the image using tuple: There is a thread error: `Xcode: EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)`

Comment: it is different issue .  it some think like that overflow exception

Comment: no problem ... sometimes that happens to me, even after several coffees